# Fastest way to make an image from a list of 2D points coordinates

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a list of points defined by their 2D coordinates (x, y).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
x = 10*np.random.randn(2000)+32
y = 10*np.random.randn(2000)+32
```

I am looking for a fast python implementation of the following code, which forms an image by filling a 2D array with these points:

```
im = np.zeros((64, 64))
dx = np.arange(64)
dy = np.arange(64)
for i in range(len(x)):
    xt, yt = x[i], y[i]
    ind_x = np.argmin((abs(dx-xt)))
    ind_y = np.argmin((abs(dy-yt)))
    im[ind_x, ind_y] += 1
    
plt.imshow(im)
```

I am looking for the fastest implementation for:

- Case 1) A large number of points
- Case 2) A large number of pixels in the image

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `dx` and `dy` are always with step = 1?

Comment: My money would be on a `numba` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are trying to create a 2D histogram for x and y.

```
np.random.seed(123)
x = 10*np.random.randn(2000)+32
y = 10*np.random.randn(2000)+32

# Create a 2D histogram of the x and y values
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=64, range=[[0, 64], [0, 64]])
plt.imshow(hist)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 2000
M = 64

np.random.seed(123)
x = 10*np.random.randn(N)+32
y = 10*np.random.randn(N)+32

xint = np.clip(np.rint(x), 0, M - 1).astype(int)
yint = np.clip(np.rint(y), 0, M - 1).astype(int)
im4 = np.zeros((M, M))
np.add.at(im4, (xint, yint), 1)

plt.imshow(im4)
```

It gives:

[image]